# Extrude edge along normal by a specified distance

Tags: edges, normals, extrude

I'm trying to create a roof on an existing building mesh. I thought I would do this by extruding this edge:

[image]

So I extruded it down the Z axis:

[image]

But I need it to go "inwards" a bit on the Y axis, like the edge of a roof does; like this:

[image]

So I tried changing the orientation of the extrude operation from Global to Normal:

[image]

But for some reason it moves the edge on the X axis:

[image]

I've verified that the normals are correct for the edge by turning on Display Split Normals in the Viewport Overlays menu. Here's a screenshot of that, from the Y/Z view:

[image]

How can I get it to extrude along the normal of the existing edge (so I guess along the Z and Y axis), without any movement on the X axis?